# How to measure temperature with thermal camera using python?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I am trying to get temperature from Flir thermal camera with Python and OpenCV in real time, as shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJy2869i_K8) video.

I am using the code below for face detection. It works for regular camera but it does not work with the thermal one, which gives me this error:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-95hbg2jt\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Render\Documents\BTK_Python\face_detection.py", line 18, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-95hbg2jt\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

```py
    import cv2
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    
    while True:
        _, img = cap.read()
    
    
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,255,0), 4)
        cv2.imshow("banu-taner", img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            break
    cap.realase()
```

Comment: Giving the whole traceback of the error might help debug it.

Comment: I updated the error I got  as seen above